# Print dynamic data in columns

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a quiz with an option to print. I don't know how many questions there are on the quiz (dynamic data from json file) and I want the print page to be in columns. each page will have 2 columns.

I don't know how long is each question and I don't want a question to start at the left columns and end at the right. a full question should be blocked.

i tried this plugin : http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/  but it's not working as i want (with this plugin question can start on the left and end at the right).

also (if that's helpful) i'm using bootstrap.

basically, this is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, without looking at your markup it would be very difficult for anyone to suggest you an appropriate solution.

Comment: `but it's not working as i want` what do you mean?

Comment: Have you tried looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/column-count ? (CSS3 columns)

Comment: @Dropout it means that with this plugin, a question can start at the left column and end at the right.

Comment: @MichaelRose, thanks but i need IE9 support

Comment: If you don't want it to end at the right question, you simply restrict the width of both columns to sth like 48%.

Comment: What happens if there are more than 10 questions?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use plain css3 column properties and page break?

`style="column-count: 2; -moz-column-count: 2; -webkit-column-count: 2;width:400px;height:200px"`

`li {
        -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
        break-inside: avoid;
    }`

example:

https://jsfiddle.net/jh2yeadf/3/

Answer (score 0):

There is option to use flexbox layout as well, but as far as I remember it's not available for IE9 (can't test it atm.)

css:

```
.container {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.insider {
  background: white;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="insider">1</div>
  ...
  <div class="insider">17</div>
</div>
```

A little demo for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/xpag09cw/

and more information regarding flexbox
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/